# Representation theorems for graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (V,E) = (V(G), E(G))$ be a graph, i.e. $V$ an arbitrary set, $E \subseteq \binom{V}{2}$ (undirected) or $E \subseteq V^2$ (directed). To be on the safe side, let me restrict to finite graphs.

Every pair of parametrized set-theoretical formulas $\mathcal{V}(x,G)$, $\mathcal{E}(x,y,G)$ determines another graph $\mathcal{C}(G)$ for a given graph $G$ by

$$\begin{array}{cclcll}
x&\in&V(\mathcal{C}(G))&:\equiv&\mathcal{V}(x,G)\\
\lbrace x, y\rbrace&\in&E(\mathcal{C}(G))&:\equiv&\mathcal{V}(x,G)\wedge\mathcal{V}(y,G)\wedge\mathcal{E}(x,y,G)&\mathsf{(undirected)}\\
( x, y)&\in&E(\mathcal{C}(G))&:\equiv&\mathcal{V}(x,G)\wedge\mathcal{V}(y,G)\wedge\mathcal{E}(x,y,G)&\mathsf{(directed)}
\end{array}$$

($\mathcal{C}$ for $\mathcal{C}$onstruction)

---

***Examples***

**The complement graph construction**
$$\begin{array}{lclcl}
\mathcal{V}(x,G)&:\equiv&(\exists v \in V)\ x = v&(\ \equiv&x \in V\ )\\
\mathcal{E}(x,y,G)&:\equiv& \lbrace x,y \rbrace\not\in E
\end{array}$$

**The line graph construction**
$$\begin{array}{lclcl}
\mathcal{V}(x,G)&:\equiv&(\exists e \in E)\ x = e&(\ \equiv&x \in E\ )\\
\mathcal{E}(x,y,G)&:\equiv& x \cap y \neq\emptyset
\end{array}$$

**The edge-set intersection graph construction**
$$\begin{array}{lcl}
\mathcal{V}(x,G)&:\equiv& (\exists v \in V)\ x = \lbrace e\in E : v \in e\ \rbrace\\
\mathcal{E}(x,y,G)&:\equiv& x \cap y \neq \emptyset
\end{array}$$

**The down-set inclusion graph construction**
$$\begin{array}{lcl}
\mathcal{V}(x,G)&:\equiv& (\exists v \in V)\ x = \lbrace u \in V : (u,v) \in E\ \rbrace\\
\mathcal{E}(x,y,G)&:\equiv& x \subseteq y 
\end{array}$$

---

For every construction $\mathcal{C}$ there is the family of graphs $G$ that are isomorphic to $\mathcal{C}(G)$. Let me call these graphs  **self-representing by $\mathcal{C}$**.

For some constructions the family of self-representing graphs can be characterized otherwise<sup>1</sup>:

- for the line graph construction, exactly the (undirected) **cycle graphs** are self-representing
- for the edge-set intersection graph construction, **all (undirected) graphs** are self-representing
- for the down-set inclusion graph construction, exactly the **complete lattices** are self-representing

For the complement graph construction I have not found a characterization of the family of self-representing graphs but [there are some examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-complementary_graph).

If a family of self-representing graphs (by a construction $\mathcal{C}$) can be characterized, we have a representation theorem for this family. Without such a characterization, we only have examples.

Searching for such representation theorems can proceed in two directions:

- Take a construction $\mathcal{C}$ and try to find a characterization of its self-representing graphs.
- Take an interesting family of graphs and try to find a construction $\mathcal{C}$ by which they are self-representing.

Note, that this approach might well be generalized to other (relational or algebraic) structures than (finite) graphs.

---

**Question 1:** Is this view on representation theorems

1. standard or folklore – or, if not so
2. in any way insightful – or
3. just a musing?

**Question 2:** Which other such representation theorems for graphs are known? (Examples of mathematical folklore are welcome!)

**Question 3:** Is there - especially - a characterization of the graphs which are self-representing by the complement graph construction?

---

<sup>1 I am aware that it is hard to fix the meaning of "to characterize otherwise".</sup>

Comment: No answer, but a minor nit to pick. In the case of an undirected graph, your definition of $\;E(\mathcal{C}(G))\;$ is$$\{x, y\}\in E(\mathcal{C}(G)):\equiv\mathcal{V}(x,G)\land\mathcal{V}(y,G)\land\mathcal{E}(x,y,G)$$And this implies (by $\;\{x,y\} =\{y,x\}\;$) that $\;\mathcal{E}(x,y,G)\;\equiv\;\mathcal{E}(y,x,G)\;$ for every $\;x,y\;$ with $\;\mathcal{V}(x,G)\land\mathcal{V}(y,G)\;$, i.e., $\;\mathcal{E}\;$ must be symmetrical in $\;x\;$ and $\;y\;$.  However, for your down-set inclusion graph construction, the definition $\;\mathcal{E}(x,y,G):\equiv x\subseteq y\;$ is not symmetrical.